# access duplicate headers from GmailMessage.getHeader()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to get the Return-Path header from a message in my add-on. I was able to get the value, however, there are multiple Return-Path entries in the header. getHeader only returns the last one. How do I get both entries with getHeader?

Below is the full code if it helps.

```
function getContextualAddOn(event) {
  var message = getCurrentMessage(event);

  var card = createCard(message);

  return [card.build()];
}

function myAction(e) {
  toAddress = e["formInput"]["forwardTo"];
  var message = getCurrentMessage(e);
  GmailApp.sendEmail(toAddress, "SPAM", message.getRawContent());
}

/**
 * Retrieves the current message given an action event object.
 * @param {Event} event Action event object
 * @return {Message}
 */
function getCurrentMessage(event) {
  var accessToken = event.messageMetadata.accessToken;
  var messageId = event.messageMetadata.messageId;
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);
  return GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
}

function createCard(message) {
  var emailFrom = message.getHeader("Return-Path");
  emailFrom = emailFrom.replace(/[<>]/g, "");
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  card.setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle("Forward e-mail"));
  
  var statusSection = CardService.newCardSection();
  statusSection.addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph()
     .setText("<b>Sender: </b>" + emailFrom ));
  card.addSection(statusSection);
  
  var formArea = CardService.newCardSection();
  var widget = CardService.newTextInput()
    .setFieldName("forwardTo")
    .setTitle("To:");
  
  formArea.addWidget(widget);
  
  var button = CardService.newTextButton()
    .setText("Submit")
    .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("myAction"));
  
  var buttons = CardService.newButtonSet()
    .addButton(button);
  
  formArea.addWidget(buttons);
  
  card.addSection(formArea);
  
  return card;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, I think that it is required to retrieve the values with `Return-Path` header from the raw content of email. In order to achieve this, how about the following modification?

### With V8 runtime:

In this case, please enable V8 at the script editor.

#### From:

```
function createCard(message) {
  var emailFrom = message.getHeader("Return-Path");
```

#### To:

```
function createCard(message) {
  // var emailFrom = message.getHeader("Return-Path");
  const res = [...message.getRawContent().matchAll(/Return-Path:([\w\s\S].+)/g)].map(([,e]) => e.trim());
```

- In this modification, `res` is an array including the values of `Return-Path` header. When 2 `Return-Path` headers are included in `message`, those are included in `res`.

### Without V8 runtime:

In this case, you can use the script without V8.

#### From:

```
function createCard(message) {
  var emailFrom = message.getHeader("Return-Path");
```

#### To:

```
function createCard(message) {
  // var emailFrom = message.getHeader("Return-Path");
  const res = message.getRawContent().match(/Return-Path:[\w\s\S].+/g).map(function(e) {return e.replace("Return-Path:", "").trim()});
```

- The result is the same with above script.

#### References:

- [V8 Runtime Overview](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime)
- [getRawContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getrawcontent)

Comment: that line gives a syntax error in the google apps script editor

Comment: @Neal Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, I thought that the reason of your issue is due to disabling V8 runtime. So in this case, please enable V8 at the script editor OR use the additional script. And test it again.

Comment: Funny thing, I could swear it said it was using the v8 runtime when I first opened the code editor. I used the "without v8" code. Thanks again.

Comment: @Neal Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.